# Cookies NOT working on different computers

Tags: php, cookies

I have website and cookies work good for that site on my computer in every browser. But for some people cookies for my site NOT working. They enable cookies in browsers, download new versions of browsers and nothing. What's the problem?

I use this code for setting cookies:

```
 setcookie("local","en",time()+126144000,"/","www.example.com");
```

Comment: Ask those people to look in their browser's cookies dialogue box to see what cookies are being stored against which web addresses.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that your site is always being accessed with the "www"? If not your cookies won't work.Try using this instead:

```
setcookie("local","en",time()+126144000,"/",".example.com");
```

Comment: I write all redirections in .htaccess to www.example.com